# Prevent word-break in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` with fixed width as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Health Department"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    />
```

... But it appears like:

```
   |Health Dep-|
   |  artment  |
```

... While I want it to be:

```
   |  Health  |
   |Department|
```

What XML attribute can I use to do this?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that these two words are going to be on separate lines every time?  If the answer is yes then you can use a "newline" within your string.  Write it like this `tools:text="Health\nDepartment"`

Comment: The width of the TextView depends on the screen density. This might be a good workaround if there is no good solution. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 48):

Try using this in TextView, this works for me

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

Comment: for API level 23 and higher

Comment: from Q and above, hyphenation is set to false by default

Answer (score 45):

From api 23 you can choose the break strategy and that should fix your issue.

By default android for TextView use [BREAK_STRATEGY_HIGH_QUALITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#BREAK_STRATEGY_HIGH_QUALITY) and that is causing the words breaking using hyphens.

If you want to avoid that, you can set the break strategy to [BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE).

You can find more information in the [api doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setBreakStrategy(int)).

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Just a note if using react native you can set this with [textBreakStrategy](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#textbreakstrategy) e.g. `textBreakStrategy='simple'`

Answer (score 19):

This is a new thing in android 6 version(Marshmallow).

Try adding the code below to your TextView in xml layout

```
android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
```

Comment: for API level 23 and higher

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to apply the break strategy mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782940/2212770) for all my textviews throughout the app and added a new v23/styles.xml containing:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Base.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:breakStrategy">simple</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And I put the following in my themes.xml

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Base.Widget.TextView</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for those wanting to **prevent text being broken into individual words** before truncation to fit the available space.

(This was how I interpreted the actual question before reading further.)  Suppose:

```
textView.setText("word1 word2")             // User sees 'word1 word2'
textView.setText("word1 word2islonger ")    // User sees only 'word1'
```

In the latter case, if you are wondering why you see only **'word1'** instead of (perhaps) **'word1 word2islo'** then the peculiarly-named ***ellipsize*** attribute is probably the culprit.

In your TextView XML, for example, try specifying

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

You will then at least see as much of the intended text as will actually fit the available space.