# How to avoid splitting strings based on UI language

Tags: android, textview

I encountered an issue that seems to be related to Androids [`breakStrategy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy) for [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)s. I use [`material-dialogs`](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to show a message (in Danish) to the user. In one of the dialogs one of the words is split in a wrong way in some cases.

It seems like it's dependent on the UI-language of the device. If the UI-language is Danish everything is good, but if I change it to English it's split in a wrong way. The texts are placed in `strings.xml` and for now it won't be translated into other languages. This however isn't a problem according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#using-framework):

> The text strings in `res/values/strings.xml` should use the default language, which is the language that you expect most of your app's users to speak.

Here is what it looks like with the device UI set to English. The word is expected to be split like "adgangs-kode".
[image: English device UI splits "adgangskode" in a wrong way]

Here is what it looks like with the device UI set to Danish, where "adgangskode" is split correctly.
[image: Danish device UI splits "adgangskode" correctly way]

I've tried setting [`tools:locale="da"`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslocale) in `strings.xml` without any luck. I know that I can set the [`breakStrategy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy), but it would be annoying to do that everywhere I use a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) and would require more work when using [`material-dialogs`](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) (since I would need a custom view).

So does anyone know if it's possible to set [`breakStrategy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy) globally (without making a custom view) or if it's possible to tell Android what language the localized text is in?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question about setting [`breakStrategy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy) globally I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931798/2761541) that uses it in styles like this in the `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:breakStrategy">simple</item>
</style>
```

This `Base.Widget.TextView` can now be set via `android:textViewStyle` in your theme. Note that the code example above only works for Android API 23+ (and thus has to be in at least `values-v23/styles.xml`), but you can still set `Base.Widget.TextView` in `values/styles.xml`. Using `textViewStyle` is also mentioned in [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d).

Answer (score 0):

Invoke follow method before activity onCreate,you need to set the special language which you really need.My example is chinese.

```
private void changeLanguage(){

Resources resources = getResources();

DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();

Locale l;

l = config.locale;

if (l.getLanguage().equals(mCurrentCountry)) {

return;

}

if (l.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("TW")||l.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("HK")) {

mCurrentCountry = "CN";

config.locale = Locale.CHINA;

}

// Log.w(TAG,"check current font scale:"+dm);

// dm.scaledDensity = dm.density;

resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);

}
```