# How to avoid word break containing non-standard character?

Tags: java, android, textview

In my application, a user enters a text. 
I put the text in the array and replace one of the letters of each word with a Japanese symbol in random order.

```
word.replace(letter, japaneseSymbol);
```

For example:

> WoあdOne　wいrdTwo　wordうhree　wえrdFour　wordFおve.

Then I display the text in TextView:

```
content.setText(TextUtils.join("　", convertedWords));
```

The problem is that the line-break is not displayed correctly:

> WoあdOne　wいrdTwo　wordうhree　w
> えrdFour　wordFおve.

I do not want to break the word.
Do you have any idea how to avoid a word break?

Comment: add whole code please

Comment: [May be this can help] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853192/prevent-word-break-in-a-textview)

Comment: @Style-7 thank you, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here － https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50547/how-to-force-a-line-break-before-the-last-word-of-a-line-reach-the-edge

```
public static String wrapString(String string, int charWrap) {
    int lastBreak = 0;
    int nextBreak = charWrap;
    if (string.length() > charWrap) {
        String setString = "";
        do {
            while (string.charAt(nextBreak) != ' ' && nextBreak > lastBreak) {
                nextBreak--;
            }
            if (nextBreak == lastBreak) {
                nextBreak = lastBreak + charWrap;
            }
            setString += string.substring(lastBreak, nextBreak).trim() + "\n";
            lastBreak = nextBreak;
            nextBreak += charWrap;

        } while (nextBreak < string.length());
        setString += string.substring(lastBreak).trim();
        return setString;
    } else {
        return string;
    }
}
```