# Android MultiLine EditText How to wrap normal

Tags: android

first I need editTextView MultiLine and wrap,but when my input include some like "-"，it wrap too Early,I just need it to show up full before the line break.
[bad wrap img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evf24.png)

my xml code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/receive_hawb_scan_hawb"
        style="@style/Edit"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:hint="@string/customs_hawb_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:text="@={viewModel.hawbNo}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/receive_hawb_scan_hawb_title"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
```

I want to it like to
[i want to wrap img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCJR1.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:breakStrategy="simple"` rather than `android:breakStrategy="high_quality"` might be what you are after.

See this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782940/15428297

Comment: I have tried, it not working